# How to get last 7 days data if from and to date is null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get all records from a table between two dates. If both the "from" and "to" dates are null then I want to fetch data of last seven days. I have written below query which is successfully giving data between two dates. How can I get last seven days of data default if both dates are null ?

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*), d.dd_value 
FROM audit_transaction t, 
     audit_master m, 
     dd_type_details d 
WHERE t.audit_id = m.audit_id 
    AND d.dd_id = m.process 
    AND m.activity_id = 9 
    AND t.iscompleted = 'completed' 
    AND audit_start_time BETWEEN '10/01/2018'::timestamp AND '10/17/2018'::timestamp 
GROUP BY d.dd_value
```

Comment: You could use `COALESCE` to set default value when input date is NULL

Comment: I don't see and `from` or `to` column in your sample query.

Comment: And if only one of them are `NULL`?  And what are the "from" and "to" dates?  There is nothing by that name in your question.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional WHERE clauses to achieve that.

If the timestamp is null it'll skip the clause on the right. Causing your query to only search the timestamps when you have one.

```
AND (v_start_date IS NULL AND v_end_date IS NULL) OR audit_start_time BETWEEN v_start_date AND v_end_date
```

Run an additional check to do the opposite, i.e. Only skip when it's null.

```
AND (NOT (v_start_date IS NULL AND v_end_date IS NULL)) OR audit_start_time BETWEEN now() AND now() - INTERVAL '7 days'
```

**Edit:** Assumed some variables from the context of a stored procedure, v_start_date and v_end_date must be timestamps.

Comment: How are you passing in your from and to dates? Is this in a stored procedure or are you statically adding your dates?

Comment: its a store procedure

Comment: I've updated that and assumed you're using 2 variables for your timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

> Use below query.

```
SELECT now(), now() - INTERVAL '7 days';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE` to check for the null value and `now() - INTERVAL '7 days'` to get your desired results.